# How do I know what distribution of data follows in R?

Tags: r, distribution

I have the following data frame.

```
IN <- c(3.5, 5.75, 9, 13.25, 13, 9.5, 9.25, 6.75, 7, 4.25, 3.25, 1.75, 0)
OUT <- c(0.25, 2, 5.25, 8.5, 10.5, 11, 11.75, 9.25, 9.5, 7, 3.75, 4, 3.5)
dat <- data.frame(IN, OUT)
rownames(dat) <- c("10~11", "11~12", "12~13", "13~14", "14~15", "15~16", "16~17", "17~18", "18~19", "19~20", "20~21", "21~22", "22~23")
```

This data is the average number of people measured in restaurants four days per hour from 10:00 am to 11:00 pm.

I want to know the distribution of IN and OUT data, respectively. How do I know this in R? Otherwise, Is there a good way to analyze this through R?

Comment: `hist(dat$OUT);hist(dat$IN)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fitdistrplus` package can help with this kind of thing, but you need to know what candidate distributions you want to check. Let's try normal, uniform, and exponential:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fit.in1 <- fitdist(dat$IN, "norm")
fit.in2 <- fitdist(dat$IN, "unif")
fit.in3 <- fitdist(dat$IN, "exp")
```

Then you can plot some diagnostics:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2)
denscomp(list(fit.in1,fit.in2,fit.in3),legendtext=c("Normal","Uniform","Exponential"))
qqcomp(list(fit.in1,fit.in2,fit.in3),legendtext=c("Normal","Uniform","Exponential"))
cdfcomp(list(fit.in1,fit.in2,fit.in3),legendtext=c("Normal","Uniform","Exponential"))
ppcomp(list(fit.in1,fit.in2,fit.in3),legendtext=c("Normal","Uniform","Exponential"))
```

[image]

Is it normal? Maybe:

```
> shapiro.test(dat$IN)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  dat$IN
W = 0.96548, p-value = 0.8352
```

Is it uniform over [0,14]? Maybe

```
> ks.test(dat$IN,"punif",0,14)

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  dat$IN
D = 0.16758, p-value = 0.8024
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The null hypotheses for these tests are that the distribution is what you think it is. The alternative is that the distribution is NOT what you are testing against. So the tinier p-values mean that a particular distribution is not a good candidate for fit.

Comment: I want to do these 4 plots to see what the distribution is for choosing an estimation method should the dependent variable only be plotted or all the variables that will be used in a regression? If my question doesn't make sense I post it here: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593526/how-to-choose-an-ordered-model-based-on-distribution-using-dependent-or-indepen)

Comment: And if it's logistic then how to test for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fitdistrplus package as follows:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
IN <- c(3.5, 5.75, 9, 13.25, 13, 9.5, 9.25, 6.75, 7, 4.25, 3.25, 1.75, 0)
OUT <- c(0.25, 2, 5.25, 8.5, 10.5, 11, 11.75, 9.25, 9.5, 7, 3.75, 4, 3.5)
dat <- data.frame(IN, OUT)
rownames(dat) <- c("10~11", "11~12", "12~13", "13~14", "14~15", "15~16", 
                   "16~17", "17~18", "18~19", "19~20", "20~21", "21~22", "22~23")

# Obtain a Cullen and Frey graph
descdist(dat$IN, discrete = FALSE)

# Fit a distribution and inspect it 
normal_distribution <- fitdist(dat$IN, "norm")
plot(normal_distribution)
```

Read more about the CF graph [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_use_Cullen_and_Frey_graph_in_data_distribution_fitting) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58220/what-distribution-does-my-data-follow).

Comment: I want to do these 4 plots to see what the distribution is for choosing an estimation method should the dependent variable only be plotted or all the variables that will be used in a regression? If my question doesn't make sense I post it here: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593526/how-to-choose-an-ordered-model-based-on-distribution-using-dependent-or-indepen)